# How to pass login_hint while using OpenIdConnectAuthentication with azure AD?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I'm using OpenIdConnectAuthentication to login my users on azure AD. I've an asp.net mvc web app. I register the OpenIdConnectAuthentication as the following in the startup class and use the [Authorize] attribute on top of the controllers. Everything works fine, but I couldn't figure out how to make the **login_hint** work. I tried passing it as a query string while calling the action. Any idea on how to make the **login_hint** work? Thanks in advance!

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `RedirectToIdentityProvider` notification.  This allows you to modify the request before the user is redirected to the identity provider.  [Vittorio's blog](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2017/03/20/tweak-sign-in-messages-with-the-asp-net-owin-middleware/) has additional details.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                    {
                        context.ProtocolMessage.LoginHint = "";
                    }
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

For more information you can check this document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application-options

```
private async Task OnRedirectToIdentityProviderFunc(RedirectContext context)
{
  context.ProtocolMessage.LoginHint = "emily@contoso.com";
  await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```